# Why don't electron microscopes use huge detectors?

Tags: electrons, microscopy

Electron microscopes have limited resolution. 
I have read experts saying that we need better electron detectors to get better resolution. 
Why can't we just use bigger detectors? Increase the distance to the detector (in vaccum of course) and the size of the detector, and it seems like resolution is merely a function of size not so much quality of the detector. Yet I don't see huge Hadron size electron microscopes being built. Why not?

Comment: @AcidJazz That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Electron microscopes are not limited by the wavelength of electrons but by the numerical aperture of electron optics and by the energy spread of their electron sources. An ideal electron microscope could get 0.1nm resolution (about the size of a hydrogen atom) with a 10eV energy electron beam, but in practice even a 10keV instrument can hardly reach that limit because of the flaws of its optics, which means that real instruments achieve only about a thousandth of the theoretically possible performance (and usually less, I believe). Ramping up the energy doesn't help with that.

Comment: Personally, I'm not convinced that we required better electron detectors to get better resolution in TEM or SEM. Now it is true that only recently have CCD camera detectors caught up with the resolution of film, but neither is really the limiting factor even in a modern aberration-corrected TEM.